# How to insert textbox values to sql server 2012 database using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have a problem with my connection to database dont know where  the exact problem is.i have to insert values of textbox to the sql server database.
here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class lbluog

    Dim myconnection As SqlConnection

    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader

    Dim ra As Integer


    Private Sub btnadddata_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadddata.Click
        myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=TAHIR-PC;database=myDataBase")

        'you need to provide password for sql server

        myconnection.Open()

        mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into tblstudentrecords([fname],[lname],[fathername],[phoneno],[address]) values ('" & txtfname.Text & "','" & txtlname.Text & "','" & txtfathername.Text & "','" & txtphoneno.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "')", myconnection)

        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("New Row Inserted" & ra)

        myconnection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

kindly anyone help me out advance in thanx

Comment: You have not provided any information about the problem is. Do you get an error, if so what is it?

Comment: No enough details... as Rhys mentioned... are there any errors? I can see from the code supplied that ra has been dim'ed but not assigned a value so at MessageBox.Show("New Row Inserted" & ra) ra is nothing. Your SQL connection string does not look complete at all...it should look something like Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Comment: it will the show the error   Login failed to the user and exception occur at connection open()

Answer (score 2):

I used your variables names mostly but cleaned up the code a little.  First I declared the SqlConnection and SqlCommand with using blocks so that they will be Disposed of properly when they're finished.  Second, I altered your SQL command and parameterized it.  This will help you avoid SQL injection exploits.  I used short form "AddWithValue" because I didn't specifically know the datatypes to declare them as they are in your database (this way should work).

```
Private Sub btnadddata_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadddata.Click
    ' Assumes your login account has permissions to the database
    Using myconnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=TAHIR-PC;database=myDataBase;trusted_connection=yes;")
        myconnection.Open()

        Using mycommand As SqlCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand
            ' Setup the SQL command with parameters.  Parameters protect from SQL injection exploits (and make your SQL easier to read/manage).
            mycommand.CommandText = "insert into tblstudentrecords([fname],[lname],[fathername],[phoneno],[address]) values (@fname, @lname, @farthername, @phoneno, @address)"
            mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtfname.Text)
            mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtlname.Text)
            mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathername", txtfathername.Text)
            mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", txtphoneno.Text)
            mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text)

            Dim rowsAffected As Integer = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' This would be one always in this case unless the statement failed
            MessageBox.Show("Rows inserted: " & rowsAffected)

        End Using

        myconnection.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

If you're having a connection issue you should post the specific Exception text (or any other Exception text you're receiving).